# How to use a variable to define the list of arguments in a function signature?

Tags: python

I'm developing a class in Python 3.7 with a function which overrides the `run` function of its base class. The `run()` function must be defined with a precise number of arguments, e.g `def run(self, a, b)`, and it will behave differently based on how many arguments are defined -- its signature is inspected when the function is called, in order to provide the right arguments number to the function. In my design, the number (and names) of arguments are passed to the class when its instance is constructed.

I've looked upon modules such as `functools` and solutions like `*args` and `**kwargs`, but I fear they won't work for my scenario, since I don't want to 'bind' any variable before calling the function, neither I do want a variable argument list. I need a fixed list of arguments for my function, but I need to define the function using a variable which is provided to the class :)

It is probably much simpler to show my expected results:

```
>>>args1 = ['arg1', 'arg2']
>>>args2 = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']

...
...

>>>c1 = MyClass(run_args=args1)
>>>c2 = MyClass(run_args=args2)
>>>import inspect
>>>inspect.getargspec(c1.run)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'arg1', 'arg2'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
>>>inspect.getargspec(c2.run)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: Is it overloading you want to do? Maybe this could help https://stackabuse.com/overloading-functions-and-operators-in-python/

Comment: I'm not sure there's a practical, sensible way to do such a thing in Python, and FWIW the whole design seems quite baroque to me. May I kindly suggest that you edit your question to explain the _real_ problem you're trying to solve with this "solution" ?

Comment: As written elsewhere, the library I am using has not been developed by me. I just need to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather strange design, because objects from the same class are expected to share common methods, hence common method signatures.

But in Python3 every object can define an attribute with a method name, and that attribute will be used when the idiom `obj.method(args)` is called. And if that attribute is a function or a lambda, it can have a signature.

Here is a minimalist code demonstrating the concept:

```
import abc
import inspect

class Base(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self, *args):
        """Just an example to show what arguments have been passed"""
        print("run method called with", *args)

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, run_args):
        """run_args is the list of the names of the arguments of run"""
        params = [inspect.Parameter(n, inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)
                  for n in run_args]
        # self.run is a lambda calling Child.run, but has a specific signature
        self.run = lambda *args: Child.run(self, *args)
        self.run.__signature__ = inspect.Signature(params)
    def run(self, *args):
        # controls that the signature of self.run has been observed
        inspect.signature(self.run).bind(*args)
        # do the processing - here only call the base class method
        super().run(*args)
```

You can now test it:

```
>>> c1 = Child(['arg1', 'arg2'])
>>> c1.run(1,2)
run method called with 1 2
>>> c1.run(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: too many positional arguments
>>> c1.run(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#119>", line 1, in <module>
...
TypeError: missing a required argument: 'arg2'
>>> c2 = Child(['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
>>> c2.run(1,2,3)
run method called with 1 2 3
>>> c1.run(1,2)
run method called with 1 2
```

Comment: This solves it! Thanks for your help :) sidenote: yep, I agree it is a strange design -- but I fear this is how the library has been implemented - not by me, though - and by the way, this strange design actually makes the class quite flexible and simple to use.